# Kendo UI Grid SignarlR datasource not firing update event

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, signalr

I'm using asp.net core razor pages with a Kendo Grid that is datasourced using SignalR. It gets the initial read ok, but the update does not fire. I've looked at the Kendo Demo, and other stackover flow pages, but nothing seems to work.

I know the API works fine in sending the update because I see the call when debugging through Chrome that the websocket received an update commmand with the new data in json format. But the Grid doesn't update, or fire any update commands. It's as if it never received it, or doesn't know that it received it.

Index.cshmtl

```
<script src="~/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = https://demosite.com/hub/controller;

    var hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .withUrl(url,
            {
                transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets | signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling 

            })
        .build();

    var hubStart = hub.start();

</script>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<myModel>
    ()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Date);

    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 98%;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .SignalR()
        .AutoSync(true)
        .ServerFiltering(true)
        .ServerSorting(true)
        .PageSize(10)
        .Transport(tr => tr
            .Promise("hubStart")
            .Hub("hub")
            .Client(c => c
                .Read("read") //Read works, initial data loads
                .Create("create")
                .Update("update")
                .Destroy("destroy")
            )
            .Server(s => s
                .Read("read")
                .Create("create")
                .Update("update")
                .Destroy("destroy")
            )
        )
        .Schema(schema => schema
            .Data("Data")
            .Total("Total")
            .Aggregates("Aggregates")
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);
                model.Field(p=> p.Name);
                model.Field(p => p.Date);
            }
        )
    )
)
.Group(g => g.Add(x => x.Name))
)
.Events(x=>
{
    x.DataBound("collapseAllGroups");
}
)
    .Groupable(true)
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(pager => pager.AlwaysVisible(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100 }))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Selectable()
    )
```

Api

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<myModel> GetTest()
        {
            myModel mod= new myModel();
            mod.Name = "New Name";
            mod.Date = DateTime.UTCNow.ToString();

            //Send update command to connected SignalR Clients
            await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("update", mod);

            return mod;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this to work. Turns out that since the Grid is originally expecting a DataSourceResult I had to convert myModel to a DataSourceResult type before doing the update. Example below should be considered Pseudocode as I’m typing this on my phone.

```
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("update", new DataSourceResult(mod));
```